# WP Как назначить класс для кастомного меню если есть наследники у пункта?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть задача по присвоение css класса `siblings` для пункта меню li если у него имеются потомки. Подскажите как это сделать ? Вот то что формирует мне менюхи в `functions.php`

```
add_theme_support('menus');
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'header_menu' => 'Меню в header',
        'footer_menu' => 'Меню в footer (Быстрые ссылки)',
    ));
});

//// Изменение атрибута id у тега li
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'filter_menu_item_css_id', 10, 4);
function filter_menu_item_css_id($menu_id, $item, $args, $depth){
    return $args->theme_location === 'header_menu' ? '' : $menu_id;
}

//// Кастомные классы для li меню
function filter_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {
        $classes = [
            'bl_nav__item'
        ];
        if($depth === 1){
            $classes = [
                'block_tab__item'
            ];
        }
        if($depth === 2){
            $classes = [
                'block_tab__item'
            ];
        }


    }

    if ($args->theme_location === 'footer_menu') {
        $classes = [
            'footer_tags__item',
        ];
    }


    return $classes;
}

/// Класс к ссылке меню
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4);

function filter_nav_menu_link_attributes($atts, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {
        $atts['class'] = '';

        if ($item->current) {
            $atts['class'] .= ' active';
        }

        if($depth === 1){
            $atts['class'] .= 'bl_tabsStructure__subTitle';
        }
    }

    if ($args->theme_location === 'footer_menu') {
        $atts['class'] = '';

        if($depth === 0){
            $atts['class'] .= 'footer_tags__link';
        }
    }




    return $atts;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4);


/// Класс ul ко второму уровню вложенности меню
add_filter('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 10, 3);
function filter_nav_menu_submenu_css_class($classes, $args, $depth){
    if( $args->theme_location === 'header_menu' ){

        $classes = [
            'block_tab__list',
        ];
    }

    return $classes;
}

//// Добавление  произвольного элемента в меню
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_button_for_mobile', 10, 4);
function add_button_for_mobile($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {

    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='".$item->ID."'");
    if($has_children) {
        $item_output = '<button class="btn_nav__mobil" type="button"></button>'.$item_output; // Add custom elements
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

Не могу найти, [какой из аргументов](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu) за это отвечает ?

На выходе хочу такое меню... с классами `siblings` если там есть второй и так-далее уровни

```
<nav class="bl_nav">
  <ul class="bl_nav__list">
      <li class="bl_nav__item"><a href="#" class="bl_nav__link">Categories</a></li>
                            <li class="bl_nav__item siblings">
                                <button class="btn_nav__mobil" type="button"></button>
                                <a href="#" class="bl_nav__link ">Top Blog</a>
                                <ul class="block_tab__list">
                                    <li class="block_tab__item"><a href="#"
                            class="bl_tabsStructure__subTitle">NewElementSibling</a>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать вот так, в функцию `filter_nav_menu_css_class` добавить проверку на то что у текущего `item` есть класс `menu-item-has-children`

```
function filter_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {

        $classes = [
            'bl_nav__item'
        ];

        if($depth >= 1){
            $classes = [
                'block_tab__item'
            ];
        }

        if ( in_array( 'menu-item-has-children',$item->classes ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'siblings';
        }

    }

    if ($args->theme_location === 'footer_menu') {
        $classes = [
            'footer_tags__item',
        ];
    }


    return $classes;
}
```

если класс `siblings` нужен только для первого уровня то тогда еще можно добавить в условие проверку на значение текущей `$depth`